# How to pass a function to a variable component in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I know how to pass a function from a parent component to a child component in React. I would like to pass function to child component after I assign the child to variable for example.

I have `Parent` component and `Child` component I assigned the `Child` component to `c` variable. After that, I would like to pass the parentFunction to variable `c` ?

```
function Parent() {

  const parentFunction =(test)=>{
    alert(test);
  }

  const c = <Chiled></Chiled>

  return (
    <div>
      {c} // How can to pass parentFunction to vaiable c

      {/* <Chiled parentFunction={parentFunction}></Chiled> */}

    </div>
  );
}

const Chiled=(props)=>{
  return (
    <div onClick={()=>{props.parentFunction("Hi")}}>google</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you can set the prop while assigning to `c`, then use `c`.

***Edit:*** OP wants to be able to create a variable out of a component and then assign props to it - I have updated my answer to reflect this.

[CodePen Mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/VoMgYQ?editors=1010)

```js
function Parent(props) {
  const handleChildClick = event => {
    alert(event.target.innerHTML);
  };

  let c = <Child />;
  c.props.onChildClick = e => handleChildClick(e)

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue" }}>
      <p>PARENT</p>
      {c}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  const handleClick = event => {
    props.onChildClick(event);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid red", margin: "5px" }}>
      <p onClick={handleClick}>CHILD - CLICK ME</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't  want to assign onChildClick={e=>handleChildClick(e)} to c variable directly, I would like to assign it after I create the c variable

Comment: My bad! - I have updated my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: @AymnAlaney - let me know if that is what you're looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Your example is working but I got the following error in my computer. TypeError: Cannot add property onChildClick, object is not extensible

Comment: How are you trying to use it? Can you post the project on GitHub?

Comment: @AymnAlaney - [here is an example using the code from your original question](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/RXLvKY?editors=1010)

Comment: @AymnAlamey I don't mind helping I'm just not sure how to see the code you're using. Cheers!